# How to change First Displaying Form in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android development. In my project there is case that I have to dynamically change first displaying form depending on a condition. Depending on a database entry I want change the first displaying form.If user is valid then i want to show home screen,otherwise login form should be displayed.Authentication is based on local app database entry.How can i achieve this?.Where i have to put this condition and navigate to another Form?

Comment: You must be having login button to navigate to home screen??

Comment: If there is an entry existing for that user in local databse,then i dont want to show login screen,it should directly navigate to Home Screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to place the Splash screen activity with Progress bar.

In background, you can check whether the user is valid or not.

If user is valid, then start Home screen.
else start Login screen.

For example:

```
if(validUser) {
startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
} else {
startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
}
```

In this example, HomeActivity and LoginActivity are the activity.

Comment: in which event,i have to write this code..onCreate or onResume

Comment: Its obvious inside the onCreate() method. Do check all the conditions inside the onCreate() method.

Comment: its correct..it should be in onCreate..earlier i tried in OnResume

Answer (score 1):

In Android you cant change first screen or home screen of your application, but you can employ following stragtegy, in HomeScreen activity, class, in onCreate check for user data in database, if it exists, do nothing, just load user data to the screen, in case of non availability startActivty LoginScreen and finish current activity, as this process will be in onCreate method and event thread, HomeScreen wont appear to user.